# Key combination for Acer erecovery doesn't work after installing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

Initially, I had 3 partitions:

```
15G recovery 
100M boot
950G Windows 7
```

I downsized the windows partition and installed Ubuntu 12 into the free space. Grub 2 found the recovery partition and added it to the menu. I can enter the recovery mode from Grub, but can't by pressing Alt+F10.

How to make Alt+F10 work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can boot recovery mode from GRUB - do it from there.
Alt+F10 option uses modified MBR record, it's possible to get this option only in price of lost GRUB.

See more:

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/243980-32-acer-laptop-recovery-help

Comment: special MBR or special boot sector in 100M partition?

Comment: Most likely both. Anyway, it's restorable, but with strings attached.

Comment: I restored mbr with `bootsect.exe /nt60 SYS /mbr`, using `bootsect.exe` from windows 7 installation DVD. Now the key combination works